connecting and disconnecting to OPCUA server not working
So in my while loop, in the first iteration i do get values for PLC Phoenix Contact and Bachman 1, but when trying to re iterate for the second time, it gives me an error for both PLC' stating
'An error occurred while retrieving values from nodes: "The attribute is not supported for the specified Node."(BadAttributeIdInvalid)
(None, None, None, None)'
i personally think i am not handeling the connecting and disconnecting events well. If there is anyone who can help, it would be greatly appreciated.
btw i have checked all the paths and mappings, and they shoudl be right. also because in the first loop it gives me all correct datapoints. Bachmann 1, however works perfectly.
so in short, i tried updating my values every 10 seconds for PLC Phoenix Contact and Bachman 1.
but the second iteration an error raises for both PLC'S.
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import StreamHandler
import telegram as Bot
import opcua
import struct
import socket
import time
import datetime
import threading
import logging
import asyncio

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

node_ids = {
    "T_C1_N1_TTV1CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N1_TTV1CA",
    "T_C1_N1_TTV1CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N1_TTV1CB",
    "T_C1_N1_TTV2CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N1_TTV2CA",
    "T_C1_N1_TTV2CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N1_TTV2CB",
    "T_C1_N2_TTV3CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N2_TTV3CA",
    "T_C1_N2_TTV3CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N2_TTV3CB",
    "T_C1_N2_TTV4CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N2_TTV4CA",
    "T_C1_N2_TTV4CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N2_TTV4CB",
    "T_C1_N3_TTV5CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N3_TTV5CA",
    "T_C1_N3_TTV5CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N3_TTV5CB",
    "T_C1_N3_TTV6CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N3_TTV6CA",
    "T_C1_N3_TTV6CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N3_TTV6CB",
    "T_C1_N4_TTV7CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N4_TTV7CA",
    "T_C1_N4_TTV7CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N4_TTV7CB",
    "T_C1_N4_TTV8CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N4_TTV8CA",
    "T_C1_N4_TTV8CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C1_N4_TTV8CB",
    "T_C2_N1_TTV1CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N1_TTV1CA",
    "T_C2_N1_TTV1CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N1_TTV1CB",
    "T_C2_N1_TTV2CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N1_TTV2CA",
    "T_C2_N1_TTV2CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N1_TTV2CB",
    "T_C2_N2_TTV3CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N2_TTV3CA",
    "T_C2_N2_TTV3CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N2_TTV3CB",
    "T_C2_N2_TTV4CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N2_TTV4CA",
    "T_C2_N2_TTV4CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N2_TTV4CB",
    "T_C2_N3_TTV5CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N3_TTV5CA",
    "T_C2_N3_TTV5CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N3_TTV5CB",
    "T_C2_N3_TTV6CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N3_TTV6CA",
    "T_C2_N3_TTV6CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N3_TTV6CB",
    "T_C2_N4_TTV7CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N4_TTV7CA",
    "T_C2_N4_TTV7CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N4_TTV7CB",
    "T_C2_N4_TTV8CA": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N4_TTV8CA",
    "T_C2_N4_TTV8CB": "ns=2;s=MIO/T_C2_N4_TTV8CB"
}

# Settings bachmann1 PLC
controller_bachmann1 = "10.178.37.111"
controller_bachmann1_Username = "M1"
controller_bachmann1_Password = "bachmann"



#If flow<5l/min  AND Total_power>500W for at least 1min
Flow = "ns=2;s=MIO/FD_T12"
#If Level=5 for at least 1min --> change this to value 350
level = "ns=2;s=MIO/Levelsensor_leaktray"

# OPC UA connection setup
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Settings bachmann 2 PLC
controller_bachmann2 = "10.178.37.112"
controller_bachmann2_Username = "M1"
controller_bachmann2_Password = "bachmann"

# OPC UA connection setup
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Settings phoenix PLC
controller_phoenix = "10.178.37.110"
controller_phoenix_Username = "OPCUAViewer"
controller_phoenix_Password = "OPCUAViewer"
# input nodes

#NODEID1 = If T_Di>80⁰C for at least 1min
Temp_Tank1 = "ns=6;s=Arp.Plc.Eclr/EQT_Inputs.Temp_Tank1.STS.ProcessValue"  #ZOEKT TEMP FROM TANK
tank1_IsOpen = "ns=6;s=Arp.Plc.Eclr/Tanks.Tank1.STS.IsOpen"
pump1_speed = "ns=6;s=Arp.Plc.Eclr/EQT_Pumps.Comm_Pump1_OPCUA.Speed_Rpm"
T_di = "ns=6;s=Arp.Plc.Eclr/EQT_Inputs.Temp_Hex_Dielectric_Inlet.STS.ProcessValue"

# Set up client certificate and private key

# heb nieuwe certificaten er al in gezet in de map
#certificate_path = r"/home/pi/safetyscript/certificate.pem"
#private_key_path = r"/home/pi/safetyscript/key.pem"
certificate_path = .
private_key_path = .

def setup_opcua_connection():
    # Setup OPC UA connection to controller
    url_bachmann1 = "opc.tcp://" + controller_bachmann1 + ":4840/"
    client_bachmann1 = opcua.Client(url_bachmann1)
    client_bachmann1.set_user(controller_bachmann1_Username)
    client_bachmann1.set_password(controller_bachmann1_Password)
    #client_bachmann1.set_security_string(f"Basic256Sha256,SignAndEncrypt,{certificate_path},{private_key_path}")

    # Setup OPC UA connection to controller
    url_bachmann2 = "opc.tcp://" + controller_bachmann2 + ":4840/"
    client_bachmann2 = opcua.Client(url_bachmann2)
    client_bachmann2.set_user(controller_bachmann2_Username)
    client_bachmann2.set_password(controller_bachmann2_Password)
    #client_bachmann2.set_security_string(f"Basic256Sha256,SignAndEncrypt,{certificate_path},{private_key_path}")

    # Setup OPC UA connection to controller
    url_phoenix = "opc.tcp://" + controller_phoenix + ":4840/"
    client_phoenix = opcua.Client(url_phoenix)
    client_phoenix.set_user(controller_phoenix_Username)
    client_phoenix.set_password(controller_phoenix_Password)
    client_phoenix.set_security_string(f"Basic256Sha256,SignAndEncrypt,{certificate_path},{private_key_path}")

    while True:
        try:
            client_bachmann1.connect()
            client_bachmann2.connect()
            client_phoenix.connect()
            print("Connection successful to PLCs")
            break  # If the connection is successful, break out of the loop
        except opcua.ua.uaerrors.BadCertificateUntrusted:
            print("The client certificate is not trusted. Please verify the certificate.")
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before retrying
        except opcua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadTooManySessions:
            client_bachmann1.disconnect()
            client_bachmann2.disconnect()
            client_phoenix.disconnect()
            print("Bad Too many Sessions.")
            if client_bachmann1.uaclient:
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before retrying
            if client_bachmann2.uaclient:
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before retrying
            if client_phoenix.uaclient:
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before retrying
            

    return client_bachmann2, client_phoenix

def retrieve_opcua_values110(client):
    global Temp_Tank1, tank1_IsOpen, pump1_speed, T_di
    #print(T_Di, tank1_IsOpen, pump1_speed)
    try:
        Temp_Tank1 = client.get_node(Temp_Tank1)
        tank1_IsOpen = client.get_node(tank1_IsOpen)
        pump1_speed = client.get_node(pump1_speed)
        T_di = client.get_node(T_di)

        # Retrieve values from the nodes
        Temp_Tank1 = Temp_Tank1.get_value()
        tank1_IsOpen = tank1_IsOpen.get_value()
        pump1_speed = pump1_speed.get_value()
        T_di = T_di.get_value()

        # print tank status
        print(f"Current values valueIN_RETRIEVE: {tank1_temp, tank1_IsOpen, pump1_speed, T_di}")
        return tank1_temp, tank1_IsOpen, pump1_speed, T_di

    except opcua.ua.uaerrors.UaError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while retrieving values from nodes: {e}")

    return None, None, None, None

#bachmann 1
def retrieve_opcua_values1100(client):
    global Flow, level
    #print(T_Di, tank1_IsOpen, pump1_speed)
    try:
        Flow = client.get_node(Flow)
        level = client.get_node(level)

        # Retrieve values from the nodes
        Flow = Flow.get_value()
        level = level.get_value()

        # print tank status
        print(f"Current values valueIN_RETRIEVE: {Flow, level}")
        return Flow, level

    except opcua.ua.uaerrors.UaError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while retrieving values from nodes: {e}")

    return None, None

def retrieve_opcua_values(client, node_ids):
    try:
        values = {}
        for key, node_id in node_ids.items():
            node = client.get_node(node_id)
            values[key] = node.get_value()
            print(f"Current value for {key}: {values[key]}")
        return values
    except opcua.ua.UaError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while retrieving values from nodes: {e}")
        return None

def disconnect_opcua_connection(client):
    try:
        client.disconnect()
        print("Disconnected successfully")
        logger.info("Disconnected successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error during disconnection: {e}")


while True:
    try:
        client_bachmann1, client_bachmann2, client_phoenix = setup_opcua_connection()

        tank1_temp = retrieve_opcua_values110(client_phoenix)        #, tank1_IsOpen, pump1_speed, T_Di
        print(tank1_temp)
        disconnect_opcua_connection(client_phoenix)

        flow, level = retrieve_opcua_values1100(client_bachmann1)
        #print(flow, level)
        disconnect_opcua_connection(client_bachmann1)

        datapoints = retrieve_opcua_values(client_bachmann2, node_ids)
        #print(datapoints)
        disconnect_opcua_connection(client_bachmann2)
        time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds before retrieving values again

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")


